# Bootstrap Togglable Menu not working after clicked one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So i have 3 tabs with images. I am able to click all the 3 images and to see the content inside. But, after i click another tab, i can't see the previous tab.

1.I click on first tab - i see the content..
2.Then i click on second tab - and i see the content..
3.When i try to click again on first tab - it doesn't work..

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php
      if(count($box_top)): $i=1;
      foreach ($box_top->getItems() as $box_item):
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-4<?php if($i<3) echo ' border'?>">
    <div class="box-focus">
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?=$box_item->abstract?>">
      <img src="../<?=$box_item->image?>" alt="<?=$box_item->title?>" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </li>
    <h2><?=$box_item->title?></h2>
    </div>
    </div>

 <?php
$i++;
endforeach;
endif;
?>

</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="WHAT" class="tab-pane fade in">
    id WHAT its from href="#<?=$box_item->abstract?>"
    </div>
    <div id="SERVICE" class="tab-pane fade">
    SECTION B content..
</div>

<div id="WHERE" class="tab-pane fade">
    Section C content...
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `<div>` element cannot be a direct child of `<ul>`. The `ul` element represents an unordered list of items (`li`) and its permitted contents is *Zero or more `li` elements*  [**w3.org**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)

Comment: you are right.. i deleted that div, and it worked.. but is there a way to use that div?

Comment: Yes, but all depends on what result you want to achieve. You could just put that divs inside another `li` element.

Comment: for each element from database it makes a new div col-md-4 and some other css.. i need that code..

Comment: As I wrote above, all depends on the result you want. I could only guess how would you like it to be (visually) so I cannot give you a specific answer (that would be my shot in the dark: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/awrnuv2g/) ). You just make sure you have **only** `li` elements directly inside `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Artur Filipiak..
I deleted all divs inside ul and added instead, ul classes to achieve similar effects.. like this:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<?php
if(count($box_top)): $i=1;
foreach ($box_top->getItems() as $box_item):
?>

    <li class="col-md-4<?php if($i<3) echo ' border'?> boxes">
    <a class="boxes" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?=$box_item->abstract?>">
    <img src="../<?=$box_item->immagine?>" alt="<?=$box_item->titolo?>" class="img-responsive boxes">
    <h2><?=$box_item->titolo?></h2>
    </a>
    </li>

 <?php
$i++;
endforeach;
endif;
?>

</ul>
```